Saving mouse coordinates in Python with pynput.mouse
I want to save three individual sets of x, y coordinates after mouse clicks, but pynput.mouse runs in an infinite loop. I can break the loop with return False, but the values of x and y are gone. Does anyone know a workaround?
from pynput.mouse import Listener
print("Click on a color")
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed:
        print('Mouse clicked at ({0}, {1})'.format(x, y)) # This value of x is printed correctly
        return False
    else:
        return False
with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
print(x). # NameError: name 'x1' is not defined.

I tried saving x and y as x1, y1, etc., but their values are also gone after the loop has been stopped. NameError: name 'x1' is not defined.

You could save x and y as global variables with global x, y

Okay, that worked, thanks, but I had to redefine x and y into e.g. x1 and y1 in order to avoid error: NAME X IS PARAMETER AND GLOBAL.
global x1, y1
x1 = x
y1 = y
